# function containing switch are not extended inline in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement

I tried to compile a program in c++ using switch statement but i got a warning message that

> **"function containing switch are not extended inline"**

, my program gave correct output but i want to know what is the meaning of this warning message.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look at http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/wrnnoinlexp_xml.html

Answer (score 1):

Will need more inputs to answer your question. (Maybe your code snippet will help understand things better)

Are you using inline keyword explicitly for the function containing switch case in your code?!
Well if you have (I presume you have) then, just wanted to say that, Compiler can ignore the request for treating the function as inline.
There are few cases where the Compiler may ignore the inline functions, they are as follows:

- Function containing a loop. (for, while, do-while)
- Function contains static variables.
- Recursive function
- Function containing **switch**
- Function containing goto statement.

Above are the few conditions which I can recollect for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not required by the standard, switch is usually translated to an array of function pointers, switch parameter being the key. Had the function been inlined, you needed a separate copy of this array in each place because function pointers might differ. This is very inefficient (both regarding memory and speed, due to how cache works), this a compiler might decide not to inline it. (A clever compiler on a clever architecture might use program counter relative addresses in this array, so this behaviour is compiler-specific.)